# get result from apply_async

Tags: python, split, multiprocessing

i am trying to use chunk and multiprocessing to import and process data from csv file. But it seems does not work when i want to get the result from the function list. I have try the `get` method and `call_back` method neither work for me.

```
def import_data(path):
        pixel = []
        label = []
        pool = mp.Pool(5)
        funclist = []
        raw_data = pd.read_csv(path, chunksize = 5000)
        for i, chunk in enumerate(raw_data):
            f = pool.apply_async(split, chunk.iloc[:,1])
            print(i) # check if enter iteration
            funclist.append(f)
            label.append(chunk.iloc[:0])  
        for f in funclist:
            pixel.append(f.get()) 
            print("get result") # check if get result(seems not)
        pixel = pd.concat(pixel)
        label = pd.concat(label)
    return label, pixel
def split(x):
    return x.str.split(" ", expand = True)
```

Comment: What is your current output

Comment: I can't get the output, it seems stop at `pixel.append(f.get())`